# Node.js Express.js Mongoose Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have this error and try evething, I read that 'return' can be one cause of the error and promise can be another one but as you can see in the code above none of this is missing in the code. In the console.log(docs) it returns the document correctly.
can any one have some solution, tks

```
exports.databaseController = (req, res) => {
   const promise = Database.find({}).exec()

   promise
    .then(docs => {
      if (!docs) {
      throw new Error('docs not found')
     }
     console.log(docs)
     return res.status(200).json(docs)
     })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)                      // not found
    return res.status(404).json({ err })  // return your error msg
  })
}

// app
const controllerDatabase = 
require('../controllers/database.controller')

module.exports = app => {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-access-token, 
       Origin, Content-Type, Accept')
  next()
 })

  app.get('/api/v1/database', 
     controllerDatabase.databaseController)
}

// server.js
require('./app/routes/database.routes')(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `console.log` . its will set the header that why you are calling 2nd time you got the error

```
 console.log(res.json(docs)) // remove
```

**Or** if you need to console.log do with direct `docs`

```
 console.log(docs)
```

Comment: tks, but still not working, with console.log(docs) I get docs but at Postmas still not respose

Comment: please check on your middleware `app.use` functions. may be you have same like console log on it. better check with error on line

Answer (score 0):

You are already sending your response in console.log. Remove the following

```
console.log(res.json(docs));
```

and this error will go away.
If you want to console log your docs do this:

```
console.log(docs);
```